# xCode 4.6 search in workspace issue..?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

Ever since I upgraded to 4.6, my global search results are not returning all locations of searched string. For ex: if I search for a specific @property name of a class to see where it's being referenced from, my result only shows those strings in the class itself, all other references are not showing up.

Did anything change? Can anyone else see this? Something with indexing maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LMAO. It turns out it was a user error. There is an dropdown with options when you click on a magnifying glass in the left corner of the search bar, where you can specify a 'style' of search which was set to 'Symbol Definitions'. Missed it somehow.

Comment: This just bit me and I was in the middle of entering a SO question when I saw this question recommended to me in a side box and it fixed my issue.   I don't have a clue how I changed it to "Symbol Definition" as it was working with "Textual" earlier tonight and I did not do anything consciously to change it.  Thanks for asking the "stupid" questions so the rest of us don't have to when we the same dumb issues ;)